# In a string with just numbers and commas how do I convert that into a double

Tags: swift, string, nsnumber, numberformatter

So I have a string with just numbers and commas. for example "1,233,323.32"(String) but I want to convert that to 1233323.32(double).

Comment: Use `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have tried NumberFormatter but Im not that skilled to understand what to do. Im new to swift

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 4: 
So basically we have a string with commas and we just remove all the commas in the string and then we use NumberFormatter to convert it to a double.

```
var newDouble = 0.0
var string = ""
string = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil) ?? ""
let myDouble = NumberFormatter().number(from: string)?.doubleValue
newDouble = myDouble ?? 0.0
```

This code only works properly if there are only numbers and commas.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NumberFormatter`:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let number = formatter.number(from: "1,233,323.32")
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will probably fail for users in a locale that uses different separators for grouping and decimal.

Comment: Yeah but this is ‘StaticString’.

Comment: I don't understand the point of your reply. For users in a locale that use `,` for the decimal separator, the value of `number` will be `nil` for a string such as `1,233,323.32`.

Comment: That's true, it fails for users with locales which use not comma separated decimal values.

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4.x:
Here is your solution with Manual Approach

```
var a = "1,233,323.32"
print(a.contains(","))
```

check how many time does ',' occurs in a String, given below

```
print("occurrence of ',': \(a.characters.filter {$0 == ","}.count)")
```

if ',' occurs 2times in string then remove ',' from String 2time using loop, given below

```
for _ in 1...(a.characters.filter {$0 == ","}.count)  {
    a.remove(at: a.index(of: ",")!)
}

print("Ans: \( Double(a)! )")
```

output

```
true
occurrence of ',': 2
Ans: 1233323.32
```